# group by SKU with count

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table with parts in it:

parts (partID, sku, ....)

The SKU looks like:

```
ABC1232
ABC1332
DSE234
XYZ322
XYZ332
etc...
```

I need to group by manufacturer, so I have to get a substring of the SKU, taking the first 3 characters and then grouping them together and getting a count of them.

So the resulting output needs to look like:

```
MFG   COUNT
ABC   2343
DSE   43
XYX   323
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(sku, 1, 3) AS MFG, count(*) AS COUNT
    FROM parts
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(sku, 1, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
SELECT  LEFT(sku, 3) AS MFG, count(*) AS COUNT    
FROM parts    
GROUP BY LEFT(sku, 3)
```

Found at [LEFT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx)